# escaping ' to &#39; in golang html template

Tags: go

How to prevent escaping `'` to `&#39;` in html template:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

const tmpl = `<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{.Title}}</title>
    </head>
</html>`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("ex").Parse(tmpl))
    v := map[string]interface{}{
        "Title": template.HTML("Hello World'"),
    }
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, v)
}
```

It outputs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World&#39;</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World'</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

[playouground](http://play.golang.org/p/q_f3dUbzOQ)

Comment: Please provide me your js library that you are using.

Comment: &#39; is fine, just leave it.

Comment: @Innovation no js, just golang

Comment: Can you provide some jsfiddle.

Comment: @Innovation sorry, it is impossible to run golang in jsfiddle

Comment: Can you tell us why you want (') rather than (&#39;) ?

Comment: @nvcnvn `&#39;` is good but `'` is better for reading html source code. It is more humanistic.

Comment: The output from `html/template` is for web browsers first, not humans.  The library is working as designed: its behavior may not be what you want, but it's doing what it says it'll do: generate HTML that's safe against code injection.  Note, in particular, that this is context sensitive: if you are doing the injection in a regular paragraph, it doesn't do the same escape (http://play.golang.org/p/wwJzpbtciv), so there must be something contextually sensitive with `TITLE` that the library understands that you are not considering.  Specifically, it's using RCDATA escaping conventions.

Comment: Specifically, see: http://golang.org/src/html/template/context.go#L98 where the library is deliberately watching for `TITLE` as a special text-escaping context.  You're asking for behavior ---human-readability---that isn't compatible with the safety concerns in the library.

Comment: To augment @dyoo's comment, the behavior is required by the spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead (look for `title` after that). It amazes me how the HTML syntax is dreadfully complex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dyoo has explained clearly that `<title>` content is treated as RCDATA. The code that does the escaping is [here](http://golang.org/src/html/template/html.go#L23). The branch `if t == contentTypeHTML` is what happens with `template.HTML`.

If you really need to control the output of the source, use `text/template` and do the escaping manually.