# Convert to Markdown in mysql foreach and add to array

Tags: mysql, sql, go, rows

I have a question!

How convert to markdown "Body" row in sql foreach and add to array?

```
type post struct {
    Id          int
    Title       string
    Body        string
    Tags        string
    Time        string
    BodyHtml    string
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Query
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM liamka_me_posts LIMIT 2")
    defer rows.Close()
    posts := []post{}
    for rows.Next() {
        p := post{}
        rows.Scan(&p.Id, &p.Title, &p.Body, &p.Tags, &p.Time)
        p.Body = html.UnescapeString(ConvertMarkdownToHtml(p.Body))
        fmt.Println(p.Body)
        posts = append(posts, p)
    }
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", posts)
}
```

PS: Added UnescapeString in line. In console it shows like `<p>HELLO</p>`, but when render page it show `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HELLO!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem in your code is in the using `&p.Body` (pointer) instead of `p.Body`.
Try it:

```
p.Body = string(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(p.Body)))
```

Also I think you want to save result of convertion into `p.BodyHtml` instead of `p.Body`.

You have to make conversation *before* you add result to array (slice), because `append` will add a **copy** of your structure into array (slice). Or you can use a pointer in your array (slice).

So, finally:

```
type post struct {
    Id          int
    Title       string
    Body        string
    Tags        string
    Time        string
    BodyHtml    string
}

for rows.Next() {
        p := post{}
        rows.Scan(&p.Id, &p.Title, &p.Body, &p.Tags, &p.Time)
        p.BodyHtml = string(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(p.Body))) 
        posts = append(posts, p)
}
```

As **elithrar** noticed, to prevent escaping HTML-specific data, use `template.HTML` type instead of `string` on that data.

Comment: Thank you very match! It works! Simple!
One moe question please! Why it converts to `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HELLO!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: The result of convertion is HTML. `"* OneTwoThree"` will convert to `<ul>
 <li>OneTwoThree</li>
 </ul>`

Comment: Do you asking why `&lt;` instead `<`? Where did you get it? Do you get it on the webpage, and you use `html/template`? Please provide more information.

Comment: but when it ExecuteTemplate this converts to `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HELLO!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: I think this post is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776525/escaping-to-39-in-golang-html-template

Comment: No! This is another problem here :)
Look how it looks http://imgur.com/kw8b5mX
Please help!

Comment: That's why you use `html/template`. That package will escape all your data. If you need to add html tags, you need to use something else. You can use `text/template` for this.

Comment: *Don't* use text/template. If you need to render one struct field as unescaped HTML, set the struct field's type to to `template.HTML` instead of `string`. Using text/template makes everything else insecure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed that in `html/template` package. Thanks!